# PHP BBcode using preg_replace() - Prevent users from entering onClick, onKeyPress

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I have a simple question (not for me), ok, at first, please take a look at this:

```
$msg=preg_replace("/\[b(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/b\]/i", "<b $1>$2</b>", $msg);
```

Okay, on that regEXP, a $msg will replace any thing found and put it into a new form (I don't know how to explain, how about an example):

It will turn

```
[b]TEXT[/b]
```

into

```
<b>TEXT</b>
```

Or it will turn

```
[b style="color: red;" title="HELLO"]TEXT[/b]
```

into

```
<b style="color: red;" title="HELLO">TEXT</b>
```

Here is where the problem springs from, what happen if it turns:

```
[b onclick="SOME TROJAN SCRIPT"]TEXT[/b]
```

into

```
<b onclick="SOME TROJAN SCRIPT">TEXT</b>
```

And all I want to do is instead of replace all attributes go after [b attribute1 attribute2...attributeN], the function will remain those attributes **AS LONG AS THEY DO NOT START WITH on** (like onClick, onMouseOver...).

I appreciate for any suggestion ^^! Thank you guys in advanced...

Comment: You can just do a whitelist of attributes to permit

Answer (score 2):

PECL offers a [BBCode package](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php). Also [PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser) eqiv, if you can't install PECL packages. Will make working with BBCode's much easier for you... once you work it out.

Comment: I will have to work it out and will notify you soon for problem! Thank you Pauly!

Answer (score 1):

Regex is rarely ever the right tool to stop HTML/JavaScript related security issues.

[Use a HTML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Comment: Could you please explain it for me. The link you gave me "DOMDocument - Manual", I didn't find what I needed there, probably I can not see it! But thanks for you reply :)

Comment: @xx3004 Everything you need is there, but if it isn't straightforward enough, try [Googling](http://google.com/search?q=php+domdocument+tutorial) for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This will be far easier to whitelist than blacklist, particularly because of the myriad of ways malicious users can obfuscate the javascript. I would make a list of acceptable entries and work from there instead. Yes, I realize that they could technically have any css entry there, but (1) you're the one who wants to allow users to create their own HTML, practically inviting all sorts of XSS headaches, and (2) this is only a `<b>` tag, so you should be OK with a small subset of allowable css commands.

Answer (score 0):

Your playing with fire but this should cure your immediate problem:

`s/\[b(\s*|\s+(?:(?!(?<=\s)on..*?\s*=\s*['"]).)*?)\](.*?)\[\/b\]/<b$1>$2<\/b>/xi`

or rx = `/\[b(\s*|\s+(?:(?!(?<=\s)on..*?\s*=\s*['"]).)*?)\](.*?)\[\/b\]/`
and replacement = `<b$1>$2<\/b>`

and some other subtle fixes.

**EDIT** A test case for sample `[b onclick="alert('HELLO');"]HELLO[/b]`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @samps = (
 '[b]TEXT[/b]',
 '[b on="]TEXT[/b]',
 '[b styleon="color: red;" title="HELLO"]TE
        XT[/b]',
 '[b onclick="SOME TROJAN SCRIPT"]TEXT[/b]',
 '[b onclick="alert(\'HELLO\');"]HELLO[/b]',
);

for (@samps) {
   print "Testing $_\n";
   if ( s/\[b(\s*|\s+(?:(?!(?<=\s)on..*?\s*=\s*['"]).)*?)\](.*?)\[\/b\]/<b$1>$2<\/b>/si ) {
      print " .. passed  $_\n";
   }
   else {
      print " .. failed\n";
   }
}
```

Output

```
Testing [b]TEXT[/b]
 .. passed  <b>TEXT</b>
Testing [b on="]TEXT[/b]
 .. passed  <b on=">TEXT</b>
Testing [b styleon="color: red;" title="HELLO"]TE
        XT[/b]
 .. passed  <b styleon="color: red;" title="HELLO">TE
        XT</b>
Testing [b onclick="SOME TROJAN SCRIPT"]TEXT[/b]
 .. failed
Testing [b onclick="alert('HELLO');"]HELLO[/b]
 .. failed
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply xD, but it doesn't seem to work when I put `[b onclick="alert('HELLO');"]HELLO[/b]`, could you please check it for me? Thank you again!

Comment: Hi @xx. It either works or it doesen't, there is no seem about it. If it doesen't work, you've done something wrong.  I'm editing my post to put up a test case using the exact **same** regular expression using your exact same sample. Please consider learning regular expressions.